# What exactly is a double stroke roll

Tags: technique, drums

I need some clarification over what is a double stroke roll . Is it **using the same hand to hit the drum once and let it bounce twice** or **using my hand to hit the drum twice in quick succession ??**

I need a clear intepretation of what is a double stroke roll !!!

Answer (score 4):

It is both.

To do a double stroke, you are making one motion of the hand (or wrist to be precise) just like a single stroke. But, you use the bounce from the hit and snap your fingers without making a full wrist motion to get the second hit. Both the hits sound same because in the first stroke, the stick is hitting from a greater distance due to the full wrist motion and in the second, you have the force from snapping the stick with your fingers.

Now take a single stroke roll and use doubles as mentioned above on each stroke and you have a double stroke roll. For someone who is looking at you doing a double stroke roll, the wrist motions would look the same like when you are doing a single stroke roll.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the speed of execution, slow - wrists or "quick succession" when played fast "let it bounce".

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on your answer a bit?

Comment: for slower tempos: lift, let bounce once, lift, let bounce once ... for fast tempo: lift, let bounce twice, lift, let bounce twice...